# Google calendar api can't get color id

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

Basically I wrote a code that should display the event name and it's hex color code, but for some reason that's not working and it displays a error called Keyerror:colorId.

I looked at https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get and couldn't understand how to solve this issue

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import datetime

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
print('Getting the upcoming 10 events and color')
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                      maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                      orderBy='startTime').execute()
colors = service.colors().get().execute()

events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    varv = colors['calendar'][event['colorId']]['background']
    print(start, varv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- In order to retrieve event colors, use `event` in the fields.
- There are also events without `colorId`.

#### Modified script :

In order to reflect above points, please modify as follows.

From :

```
colors = service.colors().get().execute()

events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    varv = colors['calendar'][event['colorId']]['background']
    print(start, varv)
```

To :

```
colors = service.colors().get(fields='event').execute()  # Modified

events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    if 'colorId' in event:  # Added
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        varv = colors['event'][event['colorId']]['background']  # Modified
        print(start, varv)
```

#### Reference :

- [Colors: Resource representations](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/colors#resource)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: It kind of works but there is one issue with it and that's that when there is no color defined and it's the default blue one. It returns a Keyerror:colorId. So I basically added this thing that if there is a colorId error, it means that the event is blue.

Comment: @Martoolius Thank you for your additional information. I couldn't notice about it. I could study from your question. Thank you so much.